# make "box-shadow" of div above of its parent's :before/:after

Tags: css

I want the css **box-shadow** of a div go outside its parent's **:before** & **:after** pseudo elements.

here you are my try:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38o4yeva/1/)

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
div.outer {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 400px;
    height: 90%;
    position: relative;
}
div.inner {
    border: 5px solid blue;
    background: #fff;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em 0.5em red;
    -khtml-box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em 0.5em red;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em 0.5em red;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em 0.5em red;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em 0.5em red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em 0.5em red;
}
div.outer:before, div.outer:after {
    content:'';
    -webkit-background-size: 10% 100%;
    -khtml-background-size: 10% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 10% 100%;
    -ms-background-size: 10% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 10% 100%;
    background-size: 10% 100%;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
div.outer:before {
    background: url(https://freebestwallpaper.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/amazing-background-1.png) no-repeat left bottom fixed;
    left: 0;
}
div.outer:after {
    background: url(https://freebestwallpaper.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/amazing-background-1.png) no-repeat left bottom fixed;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

As you notice, the **red** box-shadow get out from its parent (the **black** border on top/bottom).

I want it to be **ABOVE** the **green** left/right sides also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using pseudo elements? Why not just add the box-shadow and padding to `.outer`? Something like this perhaps: http://jsfiddle.net/38o4yeva/2/. Or if you're trying to overlap the red box-shadow on top of the black border you could do it with a single pseudo element: http://jsfiddle.net/38o4yeva/3/.

Comment: yes, I use pseudo elements :before/:after because image for the left side will be different than image on right side.

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mqzzs6b2/) the effect you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, exactly @Ana ! Thanks a lot! ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `z-index: -1` for the pseudos and removing the background from the parent does the trick.

## [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mqzzs6b2/)

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}
div.outer {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    width: 400px;
    height: 90%;
    position: relative;
}
div.inner {
    border: 5px solid blue;
    background: #fff;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em 0.5em red;
    -khtml-box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em 0.5em red;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em 0.5em red;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em 0.5em red;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em 0.5em red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em 0.5em red;
}
div.outer:before, div.outer:after {
    z-index: -1;
    content:'';
    -webkit-background-size: 10% 100%;
    -khtml-background-size: 10% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 10% 100%;
    -ms-background-size: 10% 100%;
    -o-background-size: 10% 100%;
    background-size: 10% 100%;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
div.outer:before {
    background: url(https://freebestwallpaper.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/amazing-background-1.png) no-repeat left bottom fixed;
    left: 0;
}
div.outer:after {
    background: url(https://freebestwallpaper.files.wordpress.com/2012/02/amazing-background-1.png) no-repeat left bottom fixed;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `position: absolute` to the nested element and its shadow will go on top of the parent one.